# C# String/Array Replacement

Tags: c#, arrays, string, replace

this is kinda hard to explain, but I will try my best.

So I want to have 3 TextBoxes.

TextBox 1(Input): "X:Y:Z"

TextBox 2(Input): "A:B"

TextBox 3(Output):

Now for each Line I want to Compare Y and A. Each Lines in TextBox1 Looks like this:
"ABC:123:DEF"
now it should split out 123 and compare it with A, which is splitted from B aswell.

If it equals it should give out in TextBox3: X:B:Z
If not it shouldn't give it out in TextBox3.

EXAMPLES:

```
TB1: abc:123:def 
TB2: 123:bla 
TB3: abc:bla:def
------      
TB1: abc:741:def 
TB2: 345:bla 
TB3: no output
```

This is what I got:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textToReplace = textBox1.Text.Split(':');
    var replacementArray = textBox2.Text.Split(':');

    if (replacementArray.Length == 2)
    {
        textBox3.Clear();

        for (var i = 0; i < textToReplace.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                textBox3.AppendText(":");
            }

            textBox3.AppendText(textToReplace[i].Replace(replacementArray[0], 
            replacementArray[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

IMG for 1 Line working:

[image]

For the first line it works great but not for the following. 
Thanks for all the HELP!

Comment: This is _very_ confusing.  Your question says 3 textboxes but you only give 2 examples.  I suggest editing to try to make this more clear

Comment: the third one is below if you read further

Comment: Why don't you give a **concrete** example of what textbox 1 and 2 contains, and what the **concrete** and **correct** result in textbox 3 should be. (Please edit in improve your question with this information)

Comment: Fair enough, but its still very hard to understand your desired functionality.  Maybe some formatting would make it more clear?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: You'll need to first split the inputs of the text boxes to separate lines, then apply what you're doing now.

Comment: Suggestion. Do not fill your textbox 3 immediatly with the result. Build the result first into a string variable. Use a `bool` variable to track whether replacements happened or not. Initialize it first to `false` and when in the for-loop a replacement takes place, set it to `true`. Only if this variable is `true` after the for-loop, place the composed result string into the textbox 3.

Comment: Can't you just do `if ( textToReplace[1].Equals(replacementArray[0]) ) { textBox3 = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",  textToReplace[0], replacementArray[1], textToReplace[2])}` ?

Comment: @KevinMee, why do assume that the replacement will always match textToReplace[1] and never textToReplace[0] or textToReplace[2]?

Comment: @elgonzo I am just going off his example. If not you can do the same thing in a loop

Comment: @elgonzo well if I was giving an "example" I would specify different potential scenarios...

Comment: @KevinMee, are you trying to say Frexith is a clone of you who would exactly do the same thing as you when writing and explaining a question?

Comment: guys this conversation is so off topic xD

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't get *for the first line it works but not for the following.* Do your input textboxes contain multiple lines of text? Are you hoping to process all lines of text? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: So again: In TextBox 1 there are multiple lines in Format A:B:C in TB 2 there are multiple lines in Format D:E. For every line in TB 1 in should check if B equals D in every line of TB2. if it equals it should give this out in a line of TB3. If not it should check the next line of TB1

Comment: @Frexith, unless i misunderstood your explanation in your question, AKX's comment followed by mine above should hopefully be able to guide you to a working solution...

Comment: I feel like I tried everything but none work... This is a hopeless case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a dictionary in textbox 2, so put in one, then for each line of tb1 you can search the right value.

```
string tb1 = @"abc:123:def
abc:741:def2
xxx:345:bla3";
string tb2 = @"123:bla
345:bla2";
string tb3="";

var repDic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(var line in tb2.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    var spl = line.Split(':');
    if(!repDic.ContainsKey(spl[0]))
    {
        repDic.Add(spl[0],spl[1]);
    }
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var line in tb1.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    var spl = line.Split(':');
    string val;
    if(repDic.TryGetValue(spl[1],out val))
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"{spl[0]}:{val}:{spl[2]}");
    }

}
tb3 = sb.ToString();
```

TextBox3 Output:

```
abc:bla:def
xxx:bla2:bla3
```

Comment: this was just an example

Comment: @Frexith I didn't understood your comment. The code I posted is doing what you want, for each line in TextBox1 it searches a match in all lines of TextBox2, when it finds, it post the replacement in TextBox3. What I did is put an example with fake inputs (tb1, tb2) and a fake output (tb3). Just replace the fakes inputs and outputs with your textBox#.Text

Comment: @Frexith Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what to want to achieve. I understand it this way:

1. In text box 1 you have some string with token to be replaced.
2. In text box one you have token and after `:` is strong to be inserted in token place.
3. Text box 3 is presenting result.

Basically you want to do string replace. Am I right?

Sample code:

```
var input = textBox1.Text;
var tokenArr = textBox2.Text.Split(":");
var output = input.Replace(tokenArr[0], tokenArr[1]);
textBox3.Text = output;
```

Comment: you pretty much got the problem the only thing is that it should scan every line in TB 2 before the ":" and should check if any of these equals TB1 token between both ":" if this equals then it should replace otherwise go to next line

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your code works as you want... except when it has no matches it outputs the original string instead of "nothing". So add...

```
if (textBox1.Text == textBox3.Text) 
    textBox3.Text = "";
```

Comment: If I put multiple lines it gives out nothing that's a thing

Comment: what do you mean multiple lines?

Comment: If I put in multiple lines in TB1 & TB2 in TB3 there is no output

Comment: if (replacementArray.Length == 2)... this would stop it from working... because if you had two lines with two values each... the array would have 3 values... for example: "abc:456\ndef:752" would split to "abc" and "456\ndef" and "752" where \n is a newline character... note: this is the first you've mentioned about multiple lines, right?

Comment: You would first need to do a split on '\n' and then process each separately.